# Getting a route not defined error in Laravel Blade

Tags: html, laravel

I am a Laravel/web newbie, and am working with a Laravel application inherited from someone else. In the blades, I see two ways in which forms are written.

1. `<form action="{{ route('getdata') }}"`
2. `{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'getdata','`
   I think in the first case, the form starts in HTML format  and route alone is defined in laravel format whereas in the second case, even form is defined in Laravel format. Which is preferred and what are the differences? I tried replacing the second format with the first and got a `Route [/getdata] not defined` error. Laravel Version is 6.

Comment: `{{ route('getdata') }}` is when you have a [named route](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#named-routes) defined

Comment: I would suggest to use named routes, since if you need to change it, you change it once in `routes/web.php`, and it propagates to all instances of `route('name')`. Using `url()`, or `'url' => 'name'` is a lot harder to maintain, as you potentially have to update many instances.

Comment: Post your routes `route/web.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the first example:**

`<form action="{{ route('getdata') }}"`

You are writing plain html, except for the `{{ route('getdata') }}` part, that you can read similar to `<?php route('getData') ?>`. Basically, just the action (the url) of the form is a PHP call to a function that will echo the url in that position, while the rest is plain html (an hardcoded text).

**In the second example,** `{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'getdata','` you are using a Facade to access a class that will generate an html output (similar to the code from the first example ) and you are passing to the method `Open()` an url, that will be placed inside the generated html in the `action` field.

The problem that you have using the second method, is that your are not passing your route, but a string. Change it like this:

`{!! Form::open(array('url'=>route('getdata'),'`

To fix the error of the `undefined route`, you should just call `name()`function at the end of your route:

```
   Route::('your_route_url','controller@method')->name('getdata');
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define any route named `getdata` acctually.

Change your code `route` to `url` :

```
<form action="{{ url('getdata') }}
```